# Live audio streamed over wifi

Tags: audio, wifi

Has anyone had any success taking live audio (like from an audio mixing board) into a Raspberry Pi and then streaming it over wifi to another Raspberry Pi for playback. Its very much like Airplay but with a line level music input on Raspberry Pi #1.

Thanks much!

Comment: I think this should be possible over dlna however I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: just worked perfectly with ShairPort on the pi and tuneblade on windows 11